# i am trying to install apache and mysql server on ubuntu 16

Tags: mysql

please can someone tell me why my terminal ins showing :

```
root@prince-HP-ProBook-6470b:~# apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  galera-3 iproute libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libjemalloc1
  libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 libreadline5 mariadb-common socat
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,592 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 189575 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.1 to 5.7.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.7, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@prince-HP-ProBook-6470b:~# systemctl start apache2
root@prince-HP-ProBook-6470b:~# apt-get purge apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion by running `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Did you at some point install `mariadb`? that might explain the `Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.1 to 5.7` I think

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

Answer (score 1):

Well this op shows that , you have installed mariadb prior to this and you are installing mysql server now which seems to cause this problem. Better remove mariadb, mysql-server and apache and clean cache and try reinstalling mysql-server and apache.

Remove mariadb.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb-*
```

Remove mysql-server and apache2 if installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server apache2
```

Remove unwanted dependencies and clean.

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now go ahead installing one by one. 
 *Note: Don't install mariadb and mysql-server both because fromer is a fork of the latter and both caters the same purpose.*